# How can I organize a list of fields based on another field?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, python-3.6

I am trying to show a list of items organized by their category, with their respective category name directly above it in bold. For example:

**Category 1**

- List item 1
- List item 2

**Category 2**

- List item 3

However, here is what the code currently does:

**Category 1**

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3

**Category 2**

- List item 1
- List item 2
- List item 3

**The two model classes involved taken from /models.py**:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    model_number = models.CharField('Model Number', max_length = 50)
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('Manufacturer', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length = 1000, help_text = "Enter brief description of product", null = True) #TextField for longer descriptions

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.model_number}..........{self.description}'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #Returns the url to access a particular location instance
        return reverse('model-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField('Equipment Type', max_length = 50, 
    help_text = "Enter general category of equipment")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "categories" #default would have shown as "Categorys" on admin page

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

**/model_list.html**

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div style="margin-left:20px; margin-top:20px">
      <h1>Model list</h1>
    </div>
    {% if model_list %}

      {% for category in model_list %}
        <li><strong>{{ category.category }}</strong></li>
          <ul>
            {% for model in model_list %}
              <li>
              <a href="{{ model.get_absolute_url }}"> {{ model.model_number }}..........{{ model.description }} </a>
              </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
      {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        <p>There is no equipment in the database</p>
    {% endif %}


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `ForeignKey` fields you can access one "`Model`"'s attributes from another's:

```
{% for model in models %}
    {{ model.category.category }}
    {{ model.category.help_text }}
{% endfor %}
```

Essentially - think of the field's for `manufacturer` and `category` that you have above in your `Model` as fields that are storing objects - once you get that field - your variable isn't a string or a integer, but it's an instance of the `Category` model. Then you can begin to select the attributes for that model, that is to say `model.category` is an instance of the `Category` object.

It looks like, from the way you have organised your models, that what you want to achieve is a little tricky. I would maybe advise looking at folding your categorisation of all your models in an array of objects of objects:

in `views.py`:

```
models = [ { 'category': 'categoryName', 'objects': [ SomeModelInstance1 , ... ] } ]
```

Then:

```
{% for model in models %}
    model.category
    {% for object in model.objects.all %}
         {{ object.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Let me know if this points you in the right direction...happy to help in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Does this mean that I would have to add that list in my `/models.py` file, and does it mean that I would manually have to add and pair each model instance with its category and put it in the list. For example, there are ~50 model instances and 10 categories.

Comment: @NaN You would have to do this via your views.py file using the various Model object methods, filtering methods and Q query methods Django provides. I will continue to read if Django can magically produce the above folding procedure but it may be quite a bit of digging! :)

Comment: @user9245558 I'm still a little confused about the array of objects, I've tried using `model.Model.category` as the `category` and `Model.model_number` as one of the `objects`, but it's throwing errors. Do I have the wrong idea?